# Symfony 4.0 FOSUser Bundle 2.0

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I would like to use FOSUser Bundle 2.0 with symfony 4.0 but in all tutorial on internet there is folder app which I don't have.

What i done:

Installation of FOSUser Bundle 2.0 via Composer:

```
$ composer require friendsofsymfony/user-bundle "~2.0"
```

And after that I am done because there is required /app folder whith some files which I don't have. 
Any solutions?

Comment: Master branch of `FOSUserBundle` kinda supports Symfony 4 (works but there are still things to finish up). You can check docs on the repo directly https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle and then try to adapt configurations (trial and error) knowing that Symfony 4 brings a change in directory structure of the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Symfony 4, the app/ folder was replaced by config/

Quote from [Fabien Potencier's blog](http://fabien.potencier.org/symfony4-directory-structure.html):

> Using well-known directory names helps. Using bin/, src/, or var/ was a great step forward. Symfony 4 adds etc/ in place of app/. It was proposed for Symfony 3 but rejected for reasons that don't hold anymore.
>
> Update: The etc/ has been changed to config/ after a long discussion with the community. The web/ directory has also been changed to public/. The blog posts about Symfony 4 have been updated to reflect these changes.